# audio recording upload to server using jwagener's recorder.js and recorder.swf

Tags: php, audio

I'm trying to record audio on the client side and have it shipped off to the server for processing. 
I've successfully been able to record and play the audio on the client side. My problem is arising when I need to post the information to the server.

I'm using jwageners's recorder.js : https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js#readme

I have a crossdomain.xml file located in the main directory of the site. The contents are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The post request as per his docs, looks like the following :

```
  function upload(){
     Recorder.upload({
        method: "POST",                            
        url: "http://localhost/fagaudio/recorder/recorder_server.php",  
        audioParam: "audiofile",           
         params: {                                  
           "name": "test.wav",
         },
        success: function(responseText){           
            alert(responseText); 
        },
        error: function(){                  

        }
      });
  }
```

On the server side (recorder_server.php) i'm trying something like this :

```
print_r($_POST);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fh = fopen("audio/".$name, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
```

the print_r statement returns the following :

Array
(
    [name] => test.wav
    [Filename] => audio.wav
    [Upload] => Submit Query
)

There doesn't seem to be any raw php post data and the file is being saved empty. Is there something obviously wrong in what i'm doing ? I've tried this using WAMI recorder and it works just fine but the problem is that I need to be able to post the information to the server through javascript and wami just does so automatically after every recording.

Thank you in advance for any help or input. Also if anyone is familiar with other free javascript/flash recorders out there please point me in their direction. I've already searched through stack overflow for a few recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code into php file,

```
    $save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/audio";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
  if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
    die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
  }
 }

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["tmp_name"];
$upload_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["audiofile"]["type"];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if(($type == 'audio/x-wav' || $type == 'application/octet-stream') && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) ) {

  $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
 }

  print ($saved ? "Saved" : 'Not saved');

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder

i have used this one, and it worked like charm .

You can Record, playback, and also upload the recorded file into server , here also the recorder.js is used .